# How do I give an auto width to an responsive table

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, css-tables

I have a responsive table. My only problem is how do I control the width and height of the cell as in mobile view the cells get merged

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/PCtQj/embedded/result/

Try and make the browser window smaller to a mobile view and you can see the screenshot attached:

[image]

```
/*
    Label the data
    */
td:nth-of-type(1):before {
    content:"Products";
}
td:nth-of-type(2):before {
    content:"Indication";
}
td:nth-of-type(3):before {
    content:"Target";
}
td:nth-of-type(4):before {
    content:"Preclinical Research - IN-VIVO";
}
td:nth-of-type(5):before {
    content:"Preclinical Research - IN-TOXICOLOGY";
    width:auto;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    height:auto !important
}
td:nth-of-type(6):before {
    content:"Preclinical Research - IN-VITRO";
}
td:nth-of-type(7):before {
    content:"Studies for Early Patient Data";
}
}
```

Comment: try using % instead of px

Answer (score 0):

It typically helps to make sure that we can access the page to actually edit the code, rather than just view it.

```
tr{min-width:X}
```

The solution is super easy though. Just give tr a min-width. I did it in this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PCtQj/1/embedded/result/

View the code here:http://jsfiddle.net/PCtQj/1/

The width I gave it was 500px, but you'd want to make it a bit better so that it actually responds to the viewport rather than just defining the pixels.

EDIT: I realize that there's a edit the code at the top right of the embedded/result page. But just for simplicity sake, we'll understand the problem better from viewing the code (and besides, the jsfiddle page has a small viewport that's easily resizable)